# How to prevent automatic line break

Tags: html, css

I've a div of 200px width and some text in it, how should I prevent automatic line break if the text gets longer than 200px?

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:200px;">
   Long text
</div>
```

Comment: You need `white-space: nowrap;`, also if you are using `overflow: hidden;` it will hide the text http://jsfiddle.net/VaZxU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use css property

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:200px; white-space:nowrap">
   Long text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this by following piece of code:**

```
div{
     overflow:hidden;
     width:200px;
      white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**For particular div:**

```
div#id{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:200px;
        white-space:nowrap;
}
```

I think here white-space:pre; might also work.

**Note: Its always a good practice not to use inline-css.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style

```
 white-space: nowrap
```